# (Flask) Файл создается два раза но отправляется только один раз

Tags: python, flask

Вообщем, делаю tts через flask. Использую [edge-tts](https://github.com/rany2/edge-tts).

Вот код:

```
from flask import Flask, request, send_file, make_response
import os
import subprocess
import sys
import tempfile
import io

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def tts() -> None:
    TEXT = request.args.get('text', default = 'Error')
    VOICE = request.args.get('voice', default = "ru-RU-DmitryNeural")
    keep = os.environ.get("EDGE_PLAYBACK_KEEP_TEMP") is not None
    mp3_fname = os.environ.get("EDGE_PLAYBACK_MP3_FILE")
    return_data = io.BytesIO()
    media = None
    try:
        if not mp3_fname:
            media = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=".mp3", delete=False)
            media.close()
            mp3_fname = media.name

        print(f"Media file: {mp3_fname}")

        with subprocess.Popen(
            [
                "edge-tts",
                f"--text={TEXT}",
                f"--voice={VOICE}",
                f"--write-media={mp3_fname}",
            ]
            + sys.argv[1:]
        ) as process:
            process.communicate() 
            with open(mp3_fname, 'rb') as fo:
                return_data.write(fo.read())
    finally:    
        if keep:
            print(f"\nKeeping temporary files: {mp3_fname}")
        else:
            if mp3_fname is not None and os.path.exists(mp3_fname):
                os.unlink(mp3_fname)
                return send_file(return_data, mimetype="audio/wav")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0")
```

Вот ответ:

```
Media file: C:\Users\Morgan\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpzhvy7l7m.mp3
WEBVTT

00:00:00.100 --> 00:00:01.087
hello world

127.0.0.1 - - [23/Jun/2023 01:17:20] "GET /?text=hello%20world&voice=en-GB-SoniaNeural HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Media file: C:\Users\Morgan\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp33ovjt0l.mp3
WEBVTT

00:00:00.100 --> 00:00:01.087
hello world

127.0.0.1 - - [23/Jun/2023 01:17:21] "GET /?text=hello%20world&voice=en-GB-SoniaNeural HTTP/1.1" 206 -
```